# read json file in python for respective key

Tags: python, json, encoding, character-encoding

i need to write a function in python where based on function call it return respective job_text based on job_id. Input file is in .json format
my function is as below

```
    def process(self, req, method='local'):
        request = json.loads(req)
        # Test if job text could be loaded
        job_id = request["job_id"]
        if not self.get_job_text(job_id, method=method):
            msg = "ERROR: job text could not be retrieved"
            print msg
            return msg
        else:
            response = self.map_skill_to_job_id(job_id, method=method)
            return response
```

my job_id request returned by 
request = json.loads(req) is '"408527"'
while job_id='408527', hence mismatch in the string

Anyone please help what is the issue and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads(req)[1:-1]` will trim off the first and last characters, so you can compare without the double quotes.

Comment: didn`t help, the request call is expecting value in request={dict}{u'job_id:u'408527'} format , but it getting in request={dict}{'job_id:'408527'} format

Comment: So you're saying that you need to convert the strings to unicode?

Comment: as per dry run,yes.

Comment: No , it says "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: Sorry, I guess that should be done on job_id, not the json.loads(req).